# The foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which contained the following columns.

```
ID int PK
Name nvarchar(50) NotNull
FID int FK reference to ID 

ID Name   PK
1  A      Null
2  B      Null
3  C      1
4  D      1
5  E      1
6  F      2
```

So, The primary key includes as a primary key in a table. I want to do that if the primary key is deleted, the rows which is contained the primary key as a foreign is deleted automatically. (example: When I delete ID 1 row, I want to delete automatically ID 3, 4, 5 rows.). How to make that the primary key is included as a foreign key in a table? How can I do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement a "trigger" that does a "cascading delete".

Here's a good link:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=142564

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trig

ON dbo.Table_1

FOR DELETE

AS
BEGIN
delete a from dbo.Table_2 a
JOIN
deleted d
ON a.joincol = d.joincol

END
```

Here are some other alternatives:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1508/foreign-key-vs-trigger-referential-integrity-in-sql-server/

And here is a link to Microsoft's documentation on "Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: In Microsoft SQL, a cascading delete to a self-referencing table is not allowed. You must either use a trigger, create a stored procedure, or handle the cascading delete from the calling application. An example of this is where a single table has an ID as identity and a ParentID with a relationship to ID in the same table.

[see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

Answer (score 0):

The only way will be to add a trigger you can refer the following links for more information.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/b777ec73-e168-4153-a669-835049a96520

[another link](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/778493-delete-cascade-same-table-possible.html)